# Assigning numbers in the list a color based on position

Tags: c#, arrays, list

So here I needed an array to be filled with numbers ranging between 1 to 100. 
 Then they also needed to be randomized.

Now I'm trying to assign each of the items in the list a Color, Red, Yellow, and White. This is based on position within the array with 1=Red, 2=Yellow, 3=White and needs to repeat throughout the entire array(4=Red, 5=Yellow, etc.)

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to do this.

I looked into multidimensional arrays but I'm not quite sure that would work the way I need it to. I also thought maybe a for loop could achieve this.

Or do I need to use a different enumerable to assign other values to numbers in an array.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] x = new int[101];
        Random r = new Random();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            var next = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                next = r.Next(101);
                if (!Contains(x, next)) break;
            }

            x[i] = next;
            Console.WriteLine("x[{0}] = {1}", i, x[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool Contains(int[] array, int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == value) return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're needing to fill an array of 100 elements with random red/yellow/white values?  You could (as a VERY pseudocode example): loop array[1...100] = (Math.Random()*10) % 3

Comment: Where/how do you assign a color? Or do you mean you want to print each item in a certain color/

Comment: You could create an array for the colors `string[] colors = { "Red", "Yellow", "White" };` and then you can get the color for any given index by using the modulo operator `string color = colors[index % 3];`

Comment: Where are your colors and how do they relate to a number?  Also, do you want your "random number array" to have every number from 0-100 in a random order?  Or 100 randomly generated numbers that range from 0-100?

Comment: How on earth can you mark as a duplicate when there is very little detail provided from OP?  I am voting to reopen until more details are provided.  Hopefully others will follow

Comment: Yes I have numbers ranging from 1 - 100 and they are randomized. Based on their position, I need to assign the random numbers color values so I can sort later. So lets say the 1st few elements are 84, 28, 32, 46, 17 then I would want 84 = red, 28=yellow, 32=white, 46=red, 17=yellow and continue from there throughout the entirety of the array. Does that give a better idea of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: I agree about this not being a dupe of the other question. It is not clear what OP is asking, though. One could see this as a "finish my assignment" request.

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka Do you have any code yet for the part that does the assignment of color values to numbers?

Comment: Olaf - no I am simply asking for an idea of what I should use. I've been looking for references of what could help me to achieve this but I can't seem to find a way to do this so I figured I would ask for assistance in pointing me in the right direction. I thought that was what Stack overflow was all about? I thought about multidimensional arrays but wasn't sure that would be the way to do it. After this I still have to add and remove elements and sort them in other ways. This is just one point I am stuck at right now.

Comment: This question is too broad. You're asking for two separate things: How to A) create a list of numbers comprising all the the numbers from a set, with no duplicates, but in a random order and B) assign a value (selected from a set smaller than the # in the list) to a list item based on the position of the item in the set and the list. At an absolute minimum, the question is too broad, just because it's asking for both. Frankly, there are probably multiple duplicates for these two separate tasks.

Comment: "I am simply asking for an idea of what I should use" - That's exactly what makes your question OT beyond asking two questions at once. It is clearly part of your assignment to figure out how to accomplish your task. That's a major part of programming. Copy&paste is **not programming**.

Comment: @Makyen - Well I generated the array with numbers ranging from 1 to 100. Then I randomized these numbers within the array. Now I need to assign the numbers a color based on their position in the array. There can only be three colors but need to be assigned sequentially from 0 to 99 to the elements of the array so if the first element [0] was number 84 the color needed to be assigned would be red to the first element in the array which is number 84. the next element [1] number 27 should be yellow and the third element [2] number 56 should be white.

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka: Instead of repeating what you already wrote in the text, how about writing the code? If you have that much trouble, yyou should ask your tutor, it's his job to help you. That way he might be able to adjust the course material/didactics.

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka I actually voted to close as "unclear", because exactly what you wanted isn't clear to me. In part, that's because the representation which you want to end up with is completely unspecified. It's not even clear why you need to "assign" the color values to each entry. From what you've stated, the value assigned is completely dependent upon the index into the array. This means it's just as easy to have a function which returns the value based on the index, as it it to pre-compute each of those assignments. Depending on what you're doing, it's arguably better.

Comment: So, please [edit] to clarify what the end result is that you desire. Frankly, this sounds like a homework assignment. There's nothing inherently wrong with that, it's just you appear to be giving us your interpretation of what's required rather than telling us whats actually required.

Comment: @Olaf I am not currently in any courses so unfortunately I don't have any tutor to refer to. I already have my BSIT with a concentration in Software engineering, have had 2 years experience developing in SharePoint and web development and have already taken more courses on the Microsoft Stack prepping towards the Microsoft Certs. This is not an assignment for college or any other course its just I am developing more in C# now and trying to find the right approach to complete this objective.

Comment: @Myken the reason I am trying to assign values to the random numbers is because I need remove elements later that pertain to evens and odds and what color the numbers are assigned as well as numbers divisible by another number then to sort remaining elements and display results. That is why assigning color values to the randomized numbers within the array is essential. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka: Honestly: If I had to ask such a question, I wouldn't point others at my certs or even that I work in this job since two years. Just in case one of my former teachers read it. Anyway, you seem to have found a cucumber, so be happy someone did your job _this time_. I'll leave it here.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry to somehow seeming to rub you the wrong way that was not my intention. I wasn't pointing at any certs of mine as I am working towards achieving them through prepping materials. I was merely pointing out the fact that I am not currently enrolled in any program that gives me use of a tutor and that this was not an assignment. I do appreciate you taking the time to diagnose the issue though so for that I thank you! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need randomized number generation - simply generate the numbers 1 to 100 and shuffle them. That is much faster then generating hundreds of random numbers and throwing many away (especially towards the end you "draw" lots of already existent ones by random change and do not use them).

I use poor mans shuffling by generating 100 Guids, taking theire HashCode and order the generated 
numnbers by them - thats semi random enough me thinks.

The mapping to colors I solved by generating a dictionary that maps each generated number (in order) 
to a color represented as an enum value. The current enum value is shifted with an static extension method I call after each assignment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

public enum Col { Red, Yellow, White }

public static class ColExtension
{
    // Poor mans wrap around iterator for this enum: Red -> Yellow -> White -> Red ...
    public static Col Next(this Col col)
    {
        if (col == Col.Red)
            return Col.Yellow;
        if (col == Col.Yellow)
            return Col.White;
        return Col.Red;
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        // create numbers ranging from 1 to 100. Pseudo-randomize order by ordering 
        // after randomized generated value
        var numbers = Enumerable
          .Range(1, 100).OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
          .ToArray();

        // start-color for the first one
        var aktCol = Col.Red;
        var mapping = new Dictionary<int, Col>();
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            // assign first color
            mapping[number] = aktCol;
            // advance color 
            aktCol = aktCol.Next(); 
        }

        foreach (var num in numbers)
            Console.WriteLine($"{num}, {mapping[num]}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
66, Red
24, Yellow
36, White
17, Red
86, Yellow
58, White
44, Red
27, Yellow
47, White
91, Red
15, Yellow
31, White
18, Red
25, Yellow
3, White
64, Red
32, Yellow
41, White
67, Red
11, Yellow
72, White
43, Red
9, Yellow
42, White
84, Red
23, Yellow
95, White
14, Red
59, Yellow
22, White
2, Red
76, Yellow
81, White
57, Red
19, Yellow
49, White
80, Red
55, Yellow
13, White
98, Red
1, Yellow
51, White
12, Red
90, Yellow
37, White
65, Red
26, Yellow
83, White
82, Red
61, Yellow
56, White
99, Red
78, Yellow
38, White
71, Red
40, Yellow
29, White
34, Red
93, Yellow
85, White
96, Red
39, Yellow
100, White
33, Red
74, Yellow
87, White
75, Red
92, Yellow
5, White
79, Red
60, Yellow
30, White
77, Red
4, Yellow
70, White
50, Red
16, Yellow
97, White
94, Red
63, Yellow
10, White
7, Red
73, Yellow
46, White
28, Red
45, Yellow
88, White
69, Red
62, Yellow
53, White
54, Red
89, Yellow
8, White
68, Red
20, Yellow
6, White
21, Red
48, Yellow
35, White
52, Red
```

Essentially you have a fast look-up dictionary for the colors depending on the number and an array for your numbers. I would switch to a List - but thats preference - you probably have a reason to use an array.

---

If you want to avoid storing the color values explicitly you can also convert the position "on the fly" by leveraging [linq and Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) using the overloads that provides the value and its index alongside:

```
    // local converter function - %3 gets the rest of div by 3 so 0=red, 1=yellow,...
    // the %3 makes it wrap around and the enum parse converts it to the enum
    Col ByIndexPos(int pos) => (Col)Enum.Parse(typeof(Col), $"{pos % 3}");

    // On the fly color creation from index position:
    foreach (var anon in numbers.Select( (v, pos) => 
        new { Color = ByIndexPos(pos), Value = v })
    )
        Console.WriteLine($"{anon.Value}, {anon.Color}");
```

This second approach will shift colors if you modify the base-arrays though - so if you need them to stay attached you could use the Dictionary approach.

---

*Edit* after reading some of the questions comments:

If ypu need to postprocess your data you should create a POCO (Struct/Classs) to hold: Number, Position, Color and any other attribute you need for later sorting/manipulations and the methods to operate on this data - OOP to the rescue :)

Comment: Yea I have come across using dictionary to map the elements but wasn't sure if I could use it to map the elements for what I needed to. I have also came across many different instances where people thought a list may be more plausible I just haven't seen many ways on randomizing numbers throughout a list without defining each list item, but I'm sure there is a way to do so. The array was just the first enumerable I chose to populate the random values. Thanks for your input though Patrick. It is most appreciated! I will definitely be looking more into the dictionary for this solution.

Comment: I can't upvote this post yet unfortunately because I don't have enough rep yet otherwise I would. =(

Comment: I was just looking over your code to read its flow and was just curious about your naming convention. I see you named the variable aktCol I figure Col is for color but what is akt? Is that an Acronym for something or is it non related?

Comment: @JusteasyStackAttacka  actualColor - ie- the one currently applied - a bad name, but well :)

Comment: Oh ok yea I thought that too but the k kind of through me off so I just thought I would ask.